# Whitening matrix for Fast ICA

Tags: convex-optimization, matlab, signal-processing, image-processing

I have a matrix $X $ with dimension say $ m \times n $ with $ m> n $. I am trying to whiten this matrix in matlab by first taking the $C= \operatorname{covariance}(X)$ followed by eigenvalue decomposition : $\operatorname{eig}(C)$. The whitening matrix I get is $ D^{-1/2} U' $ (where $D$ and $U$ are obtained from the eigen-decomposition. The final whitened matrix is : $ D^{-1/2} U'X $

However, I'm getting complex values here and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the covariance of a matrix? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Is the covariance XX'?

Comment: Although matlab has an inbuilt function cov(X) which finds the covariance matrix of X. Why can't that be used?

Comment: I am guessing that what is meant here by the covariance of an $m\times n$ matrix $M$ is the sample covariance between the columns. I.e. first subtract from each entry the mean of the entries in the column in which it appears, getting an $m\times n$ matrix $N$; then the $n\times n$ matrix $N'N/(m-1)$ is the the "covariance" of $M$.  I don't know about matlab, but I think that's what's done in R if you type the command "cov(M)".

Comment: @Alice : I think rather than $XX'$ or $X'X$, you first have to adjust each column of $X$ by subtracting the mean of the entries in the column from each entry, getting a matrix $Y$ then take $Y'Y/(m-1)$, where $m$ is the number of rows.  I'm not familiar with matlab, but that would make sense to me.

Comment: Maybe I should add that the "prime" means conjugate-transpose, so if all entries are real, it's just the transpose. That's conventional in a broader context than matlab; I don't actually know if matlab follows that convention, but I'll be slightly surprised if it doesn't.

Comment: (By the definition I give in a comment above, $\operatorname{cov}(M)$ is a symmetric non-negative-definite matrix if all the entries are real.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy similar to R, matlab also has a command "cov(X)" that does this.

Comment: @MichaelHardy all the components of the covariance matrix is real. However, when I do the eigen-decomposition to whiten it -- the entries aren't real anymore.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Actually - I figured it out. What MichaelHardy was saying makes sense.